# emacs: evaluate blink-matching-open when cursor highlights a parenthesis

Tags: emacs, lisp, parentheses

Recently while editing lisp code in emacs, I have been frustrated in tracking matching parenthesis.  (show-paren-mode t) helps when the matching parenthesis is visable within the buffer along with its match, and (setq blink-matching-paren t) is helpful when *writing* the matching parenthesis.  Is there a way to hook show-paren-mode so that the blink-mathing-open function evaluates as part of the "show" process?  In this manner, I can place the cursor up to a parenthesis and know what it matches against without deleting and retyping it.

Thanks,

SetJmp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
(defadvice show-paren-function (after blink activate)
  (when (= ?\) (char-before (point)))
    (blink-matching-open)))
```

Or, just use <kbd>C-M-b</kbd> and <kbd>C-M-f</kbd> to move back and forth between the point and the corresponding parenthesis.

Answer (score 2):

My favorite paren package is [mic-paren](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MicParen), which shows you the matching paren like you describe - it even works when the matching paren is offscreen (it shows some info in the echo area).

Download and put somewhere in your `load-path`, and add this to your .emacs:

```
(require 'mic-paren)
(paren-activate)
```

There are a number of configuration options you can choose from, read the comments at the top of the package.